# How to display data when an element in input is selected?

Tags: java, html, jsp, scriptlet

i want to display data when an employee is selected in input inside my table, actually i just be able to display all elements but no when employee is selected, can someone help me with the if conditional?

```
<div id="EmployeeView" class="tabcontent">
<div class="row" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;">
<tr>
    <td><input list="Assigment" required name="Assigment" class="list-assignment col-md-8" placeholder="Employee"style="border-radius: 5px;"> 
        <datalist id="Assigment">

            for (int w = 0; w < nameList.size(); w++) {

            <option value="<%=nameList.get(w).getAttUid()%>">

            out.println(nameList.get(w).getFullName());

            </option>

            }

        </datalist>
    </td>
</tr>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;" style="display: block;">

<table>
 <tr>

    int z;
    int sizeView = empDetailsMap.size();
    Employee employeeView = new Employee();
    out.println("<tr><th>Task Name</th>");
    out.println("<th>Status</th>");
    out.println("<th>Estimated Time</th>");
    out.println("<th>Actual Time</th></tr>");
    for (Map.Entry<String, Employee> entry : empDetailsMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        employee = entry.getValue();


        for (z = 0; z < employee.getTaskAssignment().getMinorTaskName().size(); z++) {
            out.println("<tr><td>" + employee.getTaskAssignment().getMinorTaskName().get(z) + "</td>" + "\n");                          
            out.println("<td>" + employee.getTaskAssignment().getTaskStatus().get(z) + "</td>" + "\n");
            out.println("<td>" + employee.getTaskAssignment().getEstTime().get(z) + "</td>" + "\n");    
            out.println("<td>" + employee.getTaskAssignment().getEstTime().get(z) + "</td></tr>" + "\n");


       <br>

       }

   }

  </tr>
</table>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting. Some of the code above is not formatted as code, making it hard to read.

Comment: Tried to fix the formatting.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question